# Calculate Mean for Each Unique Value up to a certain date

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

Data for my example.

```
date1 = seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)
date2 = seq(as.Date("2019/02/01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)
date3 = seq(as.Date("2019/02/01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)
date4 = seq(as.Date("2019/02/01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)
date = c(date1,date2,date3,date4)



subproducts1=rep("1",48)
subproducts2=rep("2",48)
subproductsx=rep("x",48)
subproductsy=rep("y",48)

b1 <- c(rnorm(48,5))
b2 <- c(rnorm(48,5))
b3 <-c(rnorm(48,5) )
b4 <- c(rnorm(48,5))

dfone <- data.frame(
                "date"= date,
               
                "subproduct"= 
                  c(subproducts1,subproducts2,subproductsx,subproductsy),
                "actuals"= c(b1,b2,b3,b4))
```

This creates Jan 2019 for date2,3,4 with value 0.

```
 dfone <-dfone %>%
 complete(date = seq.Date(from = min(date), to = as.Date('2021-06-01'), by = 'month'), 
       nesting(subproduct), fill = list(actuals = 0))
```

QUESTION: This calculates the mean for each unique sub product and replaces 0's with the mean of each, but how do I have a hard cutoff so the mean is only based off Jan-2019 to Dec-2020 and not Jan 2019 to Dec 2022?

```
library(dplyr)
dfone_new <- dfone %>%
     group_by(subproduct)  %>%
     mutate(actuals = replace(actuals, actuals == 0, 
         mean(actuals[actuals != 0], na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
     ungroup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need one more logical expression while subsetting the 'actuals' i.e. the 'date' should be `between` the 2019 Jan and 2020 Dec while calculating the `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dfone %>%
     group_by(subproduct)  %>%
     mutate(actuals = replace(actuals, actuals == 0, 
         mean(actuals[actuals != 0  & 
    between(date, as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"))], 
         na.rm = TRUE)))
```